# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError in AWS lambda function, using MicronautRequestHandler and shadowJar minimize()

Tags: gradle, aws-lambda, micronaut, gradle-shadow-plugin

I nedd reduce the jar size of 90MB to less than 50mb, i use the Shadow task and get it jar with 24mb but in aws not working.

My configuration shadowJar in gradle:

```
tasks.withType(ShadowJar) {
  mergeServiceFiles()
  minimize()
  setZip64(true)
  manifest {
    attributes 'Main-Class': 'mx.business.services.Application'
  }
}
```

used command for make jar file: **./gradlew clean build**  or **./gradlew shadowJar**

[Error in AWS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFhT6.png)

full error log

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.createConversionService(DefaultApplicationContext.java:168)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.<init>(DefaultApplicationContext.java:119)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContextBuilder.newApplicationContext(DefaultApplicationContextBuilder.java:332)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContextBuilder.build(DefaultApplicationContextBuilder.java:290)
    at io.micronaut.function.executor.AbstractExecutor.buildApplicationContext(AbstractExecutor.java:92)
    at io.micronaut.function.aws.MicronautRequestHandler.buildApplicationContext(MicronautRequestHandler.java:192)
    at io.micronaut.function.aws.MicronautRequestHandler.<init>(MicronautRequestHandler.java:96)
    at mx.business.services.lambda.SearchServicesHandler.<init>(SearchServicesHandler.java:30)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.micronaut.core.convert.DefaultConversionService.registerDefaultConverters(DefaultConversionService.java:965)
    at io.micronaut.core.convert.DefaultConversionService.<init>(DefaultConversionService.java:102)
    at io.micronaut.core.convert.ConversionService.<clinit>(ConversionService.java:36)
    ... 12 more

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.createConversionService(DefaultApplicationContext.java:168)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.<init>(DefaultApplicationContext.java:119)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContextBuilder.newApplicationContext(DefaultApplicationContextBuilder.java:332)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContextBuilder.build(DefaultApplicationContextBuilder.java:290)
    at io.micronaut.function.executor.AbstractExecutor.buildApplicationContext(AbstractExecutor.java:92)
    at io.micronaut.function.aws.MicronautRequestHandler.buildApplicationContext(MicronautRequestHandler.java:192)
    at io.micronaut.function.aws.MicronautRequestHandler.<init>(MicronautRequestHandler.java:96)
    at mx.business.services.lambda.SearchServicesHandler.<init>(SearchServicesHandler.java:30)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.micronaut.core.convert.DefaultConversionService.registerDefaultConverters(DefaultConversionService.java:965)
    at io.micronaut.core.convert.DefaultConversionService.<init>(DefaultConversionService.java:102)
    at io.micronaut.core.convert.ConversionService.<clinit>(ConversionService.java:36)
    ... 12 more

START RequestId: -- Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: ---
REPORT RequestId: ---Duration: 1634.99 ms   Billed Duration: 1635 ms    Memory Size: 1024 MB    Max Memory Used: 38 MB  
Unknown application error occurred
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```